# How to create Nested Dictionaries with user inputs

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am creating a code that involves school subjects, teachers, and the classroom they are allocated to. The user is asked what subject, then a teacher, and finally the classroom that the teacher is allocated to. 
e.g:

```
Subject = input("What subject are we talking about?")
Teacher = input("What teacher is involved?")
Classroom = input("What classroom are they teacher in?")
```

I understand there may be errors (this isn't my code, just so you get the idea). 
I pretty much want to write a dictionary like:

```
dic = {Subject(Math for e.g): {'Teacher': 'John', 'Classroom': 'U8'}
```

How would I append these inputs into a dictionary or similar format? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what you mean?

```
my_dict = {Subject:{'Teacher': Teacher, 'Classroom': Classroom }}
```

the result would be:

```
>>print(my_dict )
{'subject_name':{'Teacher': 'teacher_name', 'Classroom': 'classroom_name' }}
```

for further information to how to deal with dicts: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

to append another value just call(in case this `Subject` isn't already taken):

```
my_dict[Subject] = {'Teacher': Teacher, 'Classroom': Classroom }
```

Comment: Yeah mate that’s what I mean, I’m just curious on how to append the results into the dictionary. I know the usual .append for a normal dictionary but am unable to find how to do the multiple dictionaries in one if that makes sense.

Comment: edited accordingly...
please accept it if it meets your needs...

Comment: Hey mate, appreciate the comment and help.  (I take it you were talking about the edit in your comment, not on my code)

Comment: dont forger to click the 'V'  button bro

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this. Where am I looking?